# Check if Checkbox is selected or not from the Method in Appium?

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have a method that is checking  checkboxes not selected and I want to check through that method if I can verify if  check box is selected or not. The method verifies that checkboxes not selected.

```
class check {

   public int notselectedboxes() throws InterruptedException {
   //Checks if its not selected. 

      Thread.sleep(2000);
      int i = 0;
      for(MobileElement re: APList) {
          if(re.getAttribute("checked").equals("false"))
          {
              i++;
          }
      }
      return i;


  }


check viva = new check();
 int jk = viva.notselectedboxes();
        Assert.assertTrue(jk == true);
        System.out.println("checkbox is not  selected");
```

Comment: and what happens when you run the above code?

Comment: The checkbox is uncheck then it  clicks on checkbox through method so I don't need to click on. Do I just create another method if its checked or not. How would you do it.

Comment: Method is checking check boxes not selected. Sorry I put the wrong method.

Comment: Now `boolean jk = viva.notselectedboxes();` doesn'e make sense. Also what is `APList` used in your code?

Comment: And what would you want to assert ultimately also matters. Probably that none of the checkbox is selected.

Comment: APList its my page object. int jk = viva.notselectedboxes():

Comment: How would you do it.

Comment: So you want to put AssertFalse

Answer (score 1):

Based on the inputs as listed by you, I would rephrase the code as:

```
public int notselectedboxes(List<MobileElement> APList) throws InterruptedException {
    // Checks if it's not selected. 
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    int i = 0;
    for(MobileElement re: APList) {
        if(re.getAttribute("checked").equals("false")) {
          i++;
        }
    }
    return i; // you have returned the count on all the unchecked boxes
}
```

and further, use it as :

```
check viva = new check();
List<MobileElement> APList = ..some list of your elements
Assert.assertTrue("Some of the checkbox were selected.", viva.notselectedboxes(APList) == APList.size()); 
// if none of the boxes were selected then the method would return value equal to the size of the list of mobile elements
```